# Formatting Eplain Table of Contents Entry

Tags: plain-tex

I need to define a macro for formatting an entry in a list of tables:

```
\def\toctableentry#1#2#3{...}
```

where the first argument is the table caption, the second is the table number, and the third is the page number.

I am using the `eplain` table of contents macros to handle constructing the list, but the format of each entry needs to be as follows

```
1.4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis
    porttitor, ligula quis accumsan scelerisque, lacus nisi congue
    dolor, at pulvinar urna augue sodales leo. Vivamus pretium
    egestas sem in lacinia. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 12
```

I know how to get the leader filling to work, but I need the left-justification to work.

What I have so far goes like

```
\def\toctableentry#1#2#3{#2 #1\leaderfill #3\par}
```

with `\leaderfill` defined appropriately. This produces

```
1.4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis
porttitor, ligula quis accumsan scelerisque, lacus nisi congue dolor,
at pulvinar urna augue sodales leo. Vivamus pretium egestas sem in
lacinia. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 12
```

I suspect the solution has to do with displays, but I haven't figured out how to get that working.

**Edit**

Here is a quick, hacked together example file. The code of interest is the `\toctableentry` macro.

```
\input eplain

\def\leaderfill{\leaders\hbox to 1em{\hss.\hss}\hfill}

\def\toctableentry#1#2#3{\noindent{#2 #1\leaderfill #3}\par}

\newcount\tablenum
\tablenum0\relax
\def\table#1#2{
  \advance\tablenum 1\relax
  \xdef\tableref{\the\tablenum}
  \writenumberedtocentry{table}{#2}{\tableref}
  \hfil\vbox{
    \hsize=0.75\hsize
    \centerline{\box#1}
    \noindent Table~\the\tablenum: #2
  }\hfil
}

\readtocfile
\vskip1in

\newbox\tablebox
\setbox\tablebox=%  
  \vbox{
    \offinterlineskip
    \hrule
    \halign{
      &\vrule#&\strut\quad\hfil#\quad\cr
      height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr
      &Year\hfil&&World Population&\cr
      height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr
      \noalign{\hrule}
      height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr
      &8000 B.C.&&5,000,000&\cr
      &50 A.D.&&200,000,000&\cr
      &1650 A.D.&&500,000,000&\cr
      &1850 A.D.&&1,000,000,000&\cr
      &1945 A.D.&&2,300,000,000&\cr
      &1980 A.D.&&4,400,000,000&\cr
      height2pt&\omit&&\omit&\cr
    }
    \hrule
  }

\table{\tablebox}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duisporttitor, ligula quis accumsan scelerisque, lacus nisi congue dolor,at pulvinar urna augue sodales leo.}

\bye
```

Comment: Could `\def\toctableentry#1#2#3{\item{#2} #1\dotfill #3\par}`  work?

Comment: By the way, that `\advance\tablenum` is inside a group, so the global counter will stay at zero. Maybe you want a `\global` before it?

Comment: @morbusg I complete forgot about `\item`, but unfortunately it doesn't quite do what I need. It is difficult to tell in the example I gave that I also need the right side of the text block to be inset a bit (`\parindent` should do) with the page number extending to the margin.

Comment: @morbusg Thanks for pointing out the `\begingroup` in my example file. It shouldn't have been there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
\def\toctableentry#1#2#3{%
  \noindent
  \begingroup
  \leftskip=2em
  \rightskip=2em plus 12em % ragged right
  \parfillskip=-2em % remove the rightskip
  \llap{\hbox to\leftskip{#2\hfil}}#1\leaderfill #3\par
  \endgroup}
```

Note that `\par` must go before closing the group.

[image]

Comment: That is basically what I worked out, but yours is much nicer than mine.